# MS Excel: is 'ABCD always exactly the same as ="ABCD" in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, string

As described in the title, is 'ABCD always exactly the same as ="ABCD" in a cell? It says that all the characters after the beginning apostrophe will be treated as string, so does that essentially equal ="ABCD"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is , I tried the setup
A1 - `'ABCD`
A2 - `="ABCD"`

A3 - `=AND(A1=A2)` which gives the output `TRUE`

A4 - `=AND(EXACT(A1,A2))`gives the output `TRUE`
So it appears they are equivalent to each other

Comment: Thanks! So `'ABCD` is the syntactic sugar of `="ABCD"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

`'` means format as text
`="ABCD"` sets the cell equal to the text **ABCD**
So, testing for one equal to the other returns **True**

[image: Excel demo of equality]